# Problem : You have reached your question limit

Tags: discussion, low-quality-posts, questions, post-ban

When I try to ask a question, my Mathematics Stack Exchange account says that I have reached my question limit and should fix my previous posts. But I don't have clue how should I fix my previous posts. I also want to know whether answering questions can lift my question ban or not.
Please help me lift this ban because I have to clarify many queries on the site since this is the only place where I get answers to many of my problems .
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you read [this page from the help center](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/question-bans)? Even the moderators cannot lift the ban for you.

Comment: I have read it and I am not asking anyone to lift my ban. I am asking how should I lift this ban.

Comment: You should try and edit one of your three deleted questions or [this negatively scoring question](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1336328/11619). It is a bit difficult to give precise pieces of advice. The exact details of the formula that decides whether you have a question ban are kept secret. Read [this answer](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/19570/11619) for more information. It seems to be that by giving well received answers you can also help your cause.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This happens when several of your questions are not well-received by the community.

Some things to consider for your next questions:

- Don't ask a question and answer it later that day. Self-answering is good, but don't ask a question too fast, without researching yourself thoroughly well enough.
- Do not delete any of your questions. Deleted questions still count for the ban and if there were any answers, they will even count harder against you.

Comment: I wonder whether you noticed that you've answered a question that was asked five years ago.

Comment: @GerryMyerson I saw that it was unanswered, and I like to give back the community even if it doesn't get accepted